# What is causing white spots on my Ginseng Ficus?

Tags: indoors, ficus

I got a Ginseng Ficus 3 months ago and up to the last couple of weeks its leaves have been turning yellow. Meanwhile the ones which have been healthy have developed white spots as if lining the outer edge of the leaf. It's spring going into summer and I don't know if it's a climate change problem (it's kept indoors). I have no idea, as it's my first time having a Ficus. I've been watering every so often when the soil gets dry. The weird thing is that it seems to be healthy enough; I have new leaves budding but they die shortly. Help?

Comment: Presumably it's a [_Ficus retusa_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_retusa). Could you post some photos -- the whole plant, and a close-up of the leaves -- and describe its living conditions a bit more: how much light it gets, artificial vs. natural lighting, temperatures in your house, etc.

Comment: The living conditions are by my window.. So it gets sunlight during the day. Although at sunset I take it away from the window and put it on my counter. And for the picture I'm a newbie so I have no idea how to post a picture up.. Any advice?

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. To add a photo, click on the `edit` link under the post; there'll be a row of buttons above the edit window; the one for photos is the sixth from the left (it looks like a little landscape picture).

Answer (score 2):

Photos would be very useful, but in the meantime, find a position for it and leave it there - don't expose to sunlight, they don't like it. They like bright light, but not direct sun, nor do they like draughts.

Comment: Ficus is amazingly fussy.  Any change in their environment and they'll lose all their leaves.  Gotta have a picture to be able to make any recommendations responsibly...